# How can I get state name?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function, which receives state array (deposit, trade, withdraw), and render common data that is in each of the arrays like (transaction number, address ect)

But I have in each array unique data and I need something like this.

```
 // What I have now
 txReander(data){
 data.map((index, key) => ...)
 }

 // What I need

 txReander(data){
 data.map((index, key) => ...

 if(data.name === "deposit"){
 // do additional rendering for deposit
 }

 ... // the same for withdarw, trade
 )
 }
```

Comment: not clear what you are asking, seems like you already have a solution

Comment: what's the problem? check `map` specs and just do it